# How do i solve this exact differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the sufficient condition for the differential equation M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0 to have an integrating factor as a function of x+y. What will be the integrating factor in that case?

Comment: What have you understood and tried ?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be such an integrating factor. The condition you are looking for is:

$a'(x+y)M+a(x+y)M_y=a'(x+y)N+a(x+y)N_x$

Comment: Can you kindly post the steps? How did you come to a conclusion that a is  a function of (x+y)?

Comment: Let $a$ be an integrating factor as a function of $x+y$ an put $P(x,y):=a(x+y)M(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y):=a(x+y)N(x,y)$. If we suppose that the functions $a,P$ and $Q$ are all $C^1$ then the equation $P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$ is exact if and only if $P_y=Q_x.$